# What should the AUROC be on the test set when no positive example is present?

Tags: classification, auc, model-evaluation

Assume we have a probabilistic, binary classifier. We compute the AUROC on a test set in which no positive example is present (i.e. the ground truth is always 0). What should the AUROC be?

Comment: I agree. It seems that the $TPR$ coordinate is undefinited when you vary the threshold on probabilities. On the other hand, the $FPR$ coordinate should vary from 1 to 0 varying the threshold on probabilities from low values to high values. However, why do you need this?

Comment: @Simone Thanks. Just to know how to deal with these special case in a program. I am doing multi-label classification, and sometimes one label is always negative in the test set.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I find it odd to monkeypatch such situations by saying AUROC is undefined (this is a symptom, not the problem). What do you do after concluding AUROC is undefined? Penalize this somehow? Instead, you should fix the true problem, i.e. ensure that your test set always has all labels (e.g. through stratified cross-validation).

Comment: @MarcClaesen I am using the same code on different data set. In one data set, one label is absent from the train and sets, but is present in the test set. I'm not allowed to use the test set to train. If the AUROC was defined, it could be used when computing the AUROC over all labels. If undefined, I simply ignore it. Ideas welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The [true positive rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity#Sensitivity) (TPR), aka. sensitivity, [hit rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hit_rate), and [recall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval#Recall), is defined as $ \frac{TP}{TP+FN}$.
- The [false positive rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_positive_rate) (FPR), aka. [fall-out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval#Fall-out),  is defined as $ \frac{FP}{FP+TN}$.
- The ROC plots the TPR against the FPR.

Since the test set contains no positive example, then TP = FN = 0. This means that the TPR is undefined (division by zero), which means that the ROC cannot the plotted, which means that AUROC is undefined.